# Create a nested dictionary from a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to create a nested dictionary from a tuple. This tuple is arranged this way:

```
content=(p0,a0,b0,c0,d0,p1,a1,b1,c1,d1,....)
```

I'm trying to transform it in a nested dictionary that looks this way:

```
my_dictionary=[{"p":"p0","a":"a0","b":"b0","c":"c0","d":"d0"},
"p":"p1","a":"a1","b":"b1","c":"c1","d":"d1"},
"p":"p2","a":"a2","b":"b2","c":"c2","d":"d2"},
...]
```

The keys are always the same `keys=[p,a,b,c,d]`. My issue is that I don't know how to set this loop and how to format this in order to get the dictionary.

Comment: Which part of that are you stuck on *specifically*? See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/434287/3001761. Note that your desired output is a *list of dictionaries*; a nested dictionary would normally be a dictionary whose values are also dictionaries.

Comment: Loop through the indexes of the tuple in strides of 5, and create a dictionary with each 5 elements, and append them to the list.

Comment: I'm voting to close this. The expected output is ambiguous and there's no evidence of any attempt or effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two ways, based on the same idiomatic way of grouping elements from a sequence:

```
import itertools as it


content = range(50)
keys = ('p', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd')

dicts = [dict(zip(keys, gr)) for gr in zip(*[iter(content)]*len(keys))]
print(dicts)

dicts2 = [dict(pairs) for pairs in zip(*[iter(zip(it.cycle(keys), content))]*len(keys))]
print(dicts2)
```

produces

```
[{'p': 0, 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}, {'p': 5, 'a': 6, 'b': 7, 'c': 8, 'd': 9}, {'p': 10, 'a': 11, 'b': 12, 'c': 13, 'd': 14}, {'p': 15, 'a': 16, 'b': 17, 'c': 18, 'd': 19}, {'p': 20, 'a': 21, 'b': 22, 'c': 23, 'd': 24}, {'p': 25, 'a': 26, 'b': 27, 'c': 28, 'd': 29}, {'p': 30, 'a': 31, 'b': 32, 'c': 33, 'd': 34}, {'p': 35, 'a': 36, 'b': 37, 'c': 38, 'd': 39}, {'p': 40, 'a': 41, 'b': 42, 'c': 43, 'd': 44}, {'p': 45, 'a': 46, 'b': 47, 'c': 48, 'd': 49}]

[{'p': 0, 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}, {'p': 5, 'a': 6, 'b': 7, 'c': 8, 'd': 9}, {'p': 10, 'a': 11, 'b': 12, 'c': 13, 'd': 14}, {'p': 15, 'a': 16, 'b': 17, 'c': 18, 'd': 19}, {'p': 20, 'a': 21, 'b': 22, 'c': 23, 'd': 24}, {'p': 25, 'a': 26, 'b': 27, 'c': 28, 'd': 29}, {'p': 30, 'a': 31, 'b': 32, 'c': 33, 'd': 34}, {'p': 35, 'a': 36, 'b': 37, 'c': 38, 'd': 39}, {'p': 40, 'a': 41, 'b': 42, 'c': 43, 'd': 44}, {'p': 45, 'a': 46, 'b': 47, 'c': 48, 'd': 49}]
```

The first way creates each dictionary pairing the chunk it gets from the contents with the keys.

In terms of performance it takes

```
5.92 µs ± 42.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The second way first pairs the contents with the keys by repeating the keys alongside them, then it takes chunks of such pairs and creates a dictionary from them.

It takes slightly less, at

```
5.76 µs ± 46.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Note: in case the number of the input elements is not a multiple of the number of keys, the first solution can be modified to accommodate a partial dictionary

```
dicts = [dict((k,v) for k,v in zip(keys, gr) if v is not None) for gr in it.zip_longest(*[iter(content)]*len(keys))]
```

I understand it's not easy to explain how the chunking works to somebody who has just started with Python.

As cited in the comments, please refer to this [SO QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks) for further details

Comment: Just tried both methods, and they work perfectly. Thank you very much Pynchia. First weeks programming in Python :P.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternate solution. Basically, you are moving forward in the list by chunks and creating `dict`s that way. This is not the shortest approach, but it might be easier for a developer to understand.

```py
keys = ('p', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
index = 0
key_len = len(keys)
content_len = len(content)

output = []
while index < content_len:
    # This grabs enough values in content from the current index to match the keys
    current_content = content[index:index + key_len]

    # This creates a structure [(keys[0], current_content[0]), (keys[1], ...
    # if current_content = [1,2,3,4,5] then zip will give us something close to
    # [('p', 1),('a', 2),('b', 3),('c', 4),('d', 5)] 
    matches = zip(keys, current_content)
    # Note on the above: based on your version of Python, the output of zip may change. 
    # (In Py3k, it creates a "zip object", in Python 2.x it creates a list)
    # That will not affect this loop.

    # A list of two-entry tuples can be passed as the parameter to the `dict` class.
    current_dict = dict(matches)

    # append the output
    output.append(current_dict)

    # Be sure to move forward in the list
    index += key_len
```

Comment: This works too, thank you Cwallenpoole!  Easierr to understand than the previous answer.